# Can't update table 'transferoffer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

```
INSERT INTO Responds(ClubName, TransferID, AgentName)
SELECT c.ClubName, tf.TransferID, pa.AgentName FROM 
TransferOffer tf
JOIN
Club c ON tf.RespondingClubName = c.ClubName
JOIN FootballPlayer fp ON fp.PlayerID = tf.PlayerID
JOIN player_agent pa ON pa.PlayerID = tf.PlayerID
JOIN Agent a ON a.AgentName = pa.AgentName;
```

Im trying to insert into the table above. But I get this error below.

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1442 - Can't update table 'transferoffer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `agency_responds` AFTER INSERT ON `responds`
 FOR EACH ROW # update agency answer
UPDATE responds r
JOIN TransferOffer tp ON tp.TransferID = r.TransferID
JOIN FootballPlayer fp ON tp.PlayerID = fp.PlayerID
AND tp.Fee > fp.TransferFee
SET AgencyAnswer = "Accepted"
```

I did not understand triggers well enough. But I want to have the same routine after an insertion to the responds table. Is the logic of these code is erroneous ? Is it because I did not use .new and .old words ? 
When a new value inserted on responds table, I want to check if "tp.Fee > fp.TransferFee" and immediately update the responds table. I tried to use trigger after insert.

Comment: A trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon. You should describe the purpose of the trigger so one might be able to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: *`CREATE TRIGGER agency_responds  AFTER INSERT ON responds`* - do you want to update a lot of records in this table after inserting one new record into it? or you want to alter the column value in newly inserted record only?

Comment: i want to alter the column value in newly inserted record only

Comment: You cannot use `update` in teh trigger, just `set`. Also you need an `before update`-trigger. See e.g. [MySQL trigger before Insert value Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12836270) or [Mysql trigger to update the inserted row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33628112)

Comment: 'i want to alter the column value in newly inserted record only ' - in a BEFORE insert trigger you can alter the NEW. values please read the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html